# HoverMenuExtender only works after postback in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

HoverMenuExtender only works after postback in gridview. Weird behavior.

```
          <asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="CenterAligner" />
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Image ID="imgNotes" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/information.png"  Style="position: relative" />
                                                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlNotes" runat="server" BackColor="GhostWhite" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" Width="500px" Visible="true">
                                                            <div style="position: relative">
                                                            <div style="padding: 10px; margin: 10px; text-align: justify">
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblCreditInfo" runat="server" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblCreditWebSite" runat="server" Font-Size="9pt" Text='<%# Bind("CreditWebSite") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblCreditUserName" runat="server" Font-Size="9pt" Text='<%# Bind("CreditUserName") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblCreditPassword" runat="server" Font-Size="9pt" Text='<%# Bind("CreditPassword") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <br />
                                                                </div>
                                                        </asp:Panel>
                                                         <ajaxToolkit:HoverMenuExtender ID="hmeNotes" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlNotes" PopupPosition="left" TargetControlID="imgNotes">
                                                        </ajaxToolkit:HoverMenuExtender>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center" />
                                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

[Before Postback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVWU7.png) [After Postback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVLQN.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the panel for the balloon extender that was also on the page.